# How to change the way ModelViewSet presents the data?

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two serializers for my api to bring me data about company office locations.

```
class CountryFilialsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CountryFilials
        fields = ['name']

class FilialsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    country = CountryFilialsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Filials
        fields = ['country', 'name', 'subdomain_name', 'address']
```

CountryFilialsSerializer brings me the country name by a foreign key, and FilialsSerializer adds this data to other filial data.

A view that utilizes them both currently looks like this:

```
class FilialsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Filials.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FilialsSerializer
```

It returns the response looking like that:

```
"results": [
        {
            "country": {
                "name": "foo"
            },
            "name": "city1",
            "subdomain_name": "subdomain1",
            "address": "location1"
        },
        
        {
            "country": {
                "name": "foo"
            },
            "name": "city2",
            "subdomain_name": "subdomain2",
            "address": "location2"
        },
```

But i need it to actually present the result like this:

```
[
  {
    "country": "foo",
    "cities": [
      {
        "name": "city1",
        "subdomain_name": "subdomain1",
        "address": "location1"
      },
      {
        "name": "city2",
        "subdomain_name": "subdomain2",
        "address": "location2"
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Basically the same data, just grouped into a list by country.

I cant come up with a way to do this. As i realized, the serializer only receives one entry from the base at a time, and if i override its `to_representation()` method to include some formatting of the output, i wont be able to access multiple locations and group them by one country.
My next guess was that there should be similar way to work with the result directly from the view.
But i couldnt find anything about it in documentation (or maybe i didnt know what to even look for).
Found some info about actions, and update() method, but couldnt get how to utilize it for my goal.
Can you please suggest something? I dont get where and how do i put the logic into the view to be able to catch everything it shoves into the response and reorganize it.

Comment: You can use `to_representation(self, instance)` in `FilialsSerializer` the  to tailor the data. Then you can do whatever you want with the data that will be displayed, even add new fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the list of countries with cities like this (this would require you to change the view the use `CountryFilialsViewset`)

```
class FilialsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Filials
        fields = ['name',]

class CountryFilialsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filials = FilialsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CountryFilials
        fields = ['name', 'filials']

class CountryFilialsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CountryFilials.objects.prefetch_related('filials')
    serializer_class = CountryFilialsSerializer
```

Or if you need to override the `ModelViewSet` you could do something like this:

```
class CountryFilialsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CountryFilials.objects.prefetch_related('filials_set')
    serializer_class = CountryFilialsSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        response = [
            {'country': country.name, 'cities': list(country.filials_set.values('name').all())} for country in CountryFilials.objects.all()
        ]
        return Response(response)
```

**EDIT:** change `filials` to `filials_set`

Here is an example on how to change the fields names and data:

```
class FilialsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_url')
    class Meta:
        model = Filials
        fields = ['name', 'url', 'address']

    def get_url(self, obj):
        # construct the url
        return  f'http://{obj.subdomain_name}.example.com/api/v1/cities/'

class CountryFilialsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filials = FilialsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='filials_set')
    class Meta:
        model = CountryFilials
        fields = ['name', 'filials']

class CountryFilialsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CountryFilials.objects.prefetch_related('filials_set')
    serializer_class = CountryFilialsSerializer
```

You would get the results you want using the `CountryFilialsViewSet`. for example in your `urls.py` you would have

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'filials', CountryFilialsViewSet),

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Calling `http://api/filials` would yield the response.

Comment: The first approach doesnt seem to work. "Cannot find 'filials' on CountryFilials object, 'filials' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()". Initially i thought you were trying to invoke the line "filials = FilialsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)" when using the prefetch_related on CountryFilials model, but then i realized why it probably doesnt work: there is no field "filials" in the model itself, and because of this i now dont understand your suggestion at all. Same thing with the second approach, i dont get what exactly are you trying to prefetch here.

Comment: my bad, `filials` is just a `related_name` I added in my model declaration, you can change it to `filials_set` to get the reverse foreign key. the method `list` is what you need to override if you want to change the response on GET

Comment: Thanks, it now renders the view, however there are still some issues i cant grasp the solutions for. Your first approach (after changing into filials_set) only returns country names for some reason, and doesnt include anything else from FilialsSerializer into the response. The second approach looks even trickier: it does show all the names of the filials in a list under their respective countries, but i dont get how i can include other fields into it, since it simply lists the names without any connection to the other fields.

Comment: You add the fields you want to have in `FilialsSerializer.Meta.fields` I only add `name` but you can any other model field, same for the second approach, you can any field in `list(country.filials_set.values('name', 'subdomain_name', ... other fields ).all())`

Comment: Okay, i have one last question then if you dont mind. Is there a way to change the fields name in this scenario? Like, get a "subdomain_name" field, but show it as a "url" field, maybe adding another str to it to make it a full url? The endpoints of the front i'm trying to work with require specific names and data composition, and i'm so tired of trying to do this as my first task ever as an intern without any supervision while having scarce knowledge of the framework and no superiors to ask for help.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment